# SQL Server 2008 R2 SQL Server has encountered x occurrence(s) of I/O requests taking longer than 15 seconds to complete on file '

Tags: sql-server-2008

When I alter or create a stored procedure directly on production or QA database, after a few seconds I start experience timeouts and application becomes unavailable.

Log files shows this error:

> SQL Server has encountered 3 occurrence(s) of I/O requests taking
>   longer than 15 seconds to complete on file [C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\QA_Database.ldf] in
>   database [QA_Database] (9).  The OS file handle is 0x0000000000000568.
>   The offset of the latest long I/O is: 0x0000002821a200

We have SQL Server 2008 R2 installed, including latest Service Pack.

I tried to reproduce it on QA, but to no avail. I have no clue what it could be.

Stored procedure execution time is around 1 second and it runs occasionally. It returns just few records. It happened with 2 different stored procedures and I think that changing, not running, a stored procedure triggered something that caused the issue.
Once I deleted it, issue was gone immediately.

Comment: Is this a very large or complicated stored procedure? What would be its typical execution time? How frequently is it called (10s of calls per second, hundreds per second)? How large is the database? How much traffic is the server dealing with?

Comment: Stored procedure execution time is around 1 second and it runs occasionally. It returns just few records. It happened with 2 different stored procedures and I think that changing, not running, a stored procedure triggered something that caused the issue. Once I deleted it, issue was gone immediately.

Comment: Well the first issue I see on this is that you have the database on the "C:" drive of your server. That is the same drive your OS is on running. Simply moving the database files off to another drive might fix your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Just a hunch... is that ldf growing when you get this error? I seen this error a few times and always been that someone set the growthrate in too big steps for the io subsystem to handle at same time as normal io within 15 seconds. Go and see if it happens to bet set to 10% and how big a step that would be. If it is GBs you might want to set it to a smaller size to grow and also in MB instead of percent.

Who knows I might get lucky on this one ;-)

Comment: +1 I like your thinking, that's an educated shot in the dark.

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue with the underlying IO subsystem for that database. It could be for a variety of reasons but the SQL Server is clearly struggling to read / write data.

You will be able to get more help on serverfault, and they will want the details about the IO subsystem to suggest metrics to check.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. We tested IO system. It works very well on production.
Also, production server and staging are two complete different environments.

Comment: There are some blogged troubleshooting guides : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrissk/archive/2008/06/19/i-o-requests-taking-longer-than-15-seconds-to-complete-on-file.aspx The problem though is going to be configuration / hardware in some form, and not programming - thus serverfault is the ideal community to ask